# Scroll page whist designing app for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollview

I am designing a windows phone app in visual studio, and the data it contains is huge, which makes it to occupy large space of the page. How I can scroll the page in design view so I can add controls and so on on the bottom. 
I welcome any kind of help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the number of data items?

Set the top margin in a way that the whole container goes outside of scope but on the top, not on the bottom, and then just reset it when you're done.

Comment: @Igrali...thanks for the advice..I changed the default design height of 800 to a bigger number such as 1800, and now it shows me the entire page, so I can manipulate the bottom the way I like..and then just gonna change the design height back to its default 800..thanks